# how to manage z-index on carousel elements?

Tags: javascript, css, css-transforms

I want to create a infinite carousel, with the top-left picture sliding to the right-end of the list of elements, passing behind the others.

My problem is the transformX, which creates a new stack for z-index, in a way I can't have my element to be really behind all others.

I'm using plain javascript, and you can see the actual result in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sjpouxer/23/)

```
    <div id="galerie" style="display: flex;">
      <div class="picture" style="background-color: black; width: 100px;">
        <p>picture 1</p>
      </div>     
      <div class="picture" style="background-color: blue; width: 100px;">
        <p>picture 2</p>
      </div>  
      <div class="picture" style="background-color: orange; width: 100px;">
        <p>picture 3</p>
      </div>
      <div class="picture" style="background-color: green; width: 100px;">
        <p>picture 4</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

```
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var slider = document.querySelector('#galerie');
        var items = slider.querySelectorAll('.picture');

        let currentIndex = 0;

        function moveItems() {
            currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % items.length;
            let translationVector;
            items.forEach((item, index) => {
                item.style.zIndex = 0;
                if (index === currentIndex -2 || (index === (items.length -2) && currentIndex === 0) || (index === (items.length -1) && currentIndex === 1)) {
                    item.style.zIndex = -100;
                } 
                if (currentIndex == 0) {
                    if (index == items.length - 1){
                        translationVector = items.length * -100
                    } else {
                        translationVector = 0;
                    }
                    
                } else if ( currentIndex == 1) {
                    translationVector = -100;
                } else if (index < currentIndex - 1){
                    translationVector = (items.length - currentIndex) *100;
                } else {
                    translationVector = -currentIndex * 100;
                }

                item.style.transform = `translateX(${translationVector}px)`;
                if (index === currentIndex -2 || (index === (items.length -2) && currentIndex === 0) || (index === (items.length -1) && currentIndex === 1)) {
                    item.style.zIndex = 0;
                }            
            })
        }
        if (items.length > 2){
            setInterval(moveItems, 5000); // Move items every 5 seconds
        }
    });
```

At the first step of the carousel, picture 0 goes to the left (it will be partially hidden by overflow: hidden on parent), and others pictures also move 1 step left.

At the second step, picture 0 moves to the right, BEHIND the other pictures. Other pictures continue to move one step left.

At the third step, picture 1 moves to the right, BEHIND the other pictures, except it passes IN FRONT OF picture 0. It should move BEHIND ALL other pictures. Other pictures move one step left.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your problem is with the transform step, which creates a new z-index stack. When you apply a transform on an element, the elements goes to a new stacking context. See https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_positioned_layout/Understanding_z-index/Stacking_context